# Synchronize MySQL database from remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, data-synchronization

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html) mentions a sync function, but that function is not available from the `Database` menu as shown in the screenshots there. Is this functionality available elsewhere? Using `reverse engineer` makes the option show, but the wizard is unclear..

It would be nice being able to choose specific tables, but have the necessary tables linked through foreign keys be automatically included to avoid synchronization failure, and to do it all from the mysql shell not from an error prone UI.

Comment: in workbecnh press ctrl+R or do reverse engineer and then you can view the given options under Database tab option

Comment: what do the warnings about development environments mean? can this break a database, even a development/staging one?

Comment: If they have to break you may have faced errors not the warnings. Try to resolve warnings if possible or you may proceed further and see what it does at the end. Would be better to do it on testing machines first and to see if everything works as perceived.

Comment: Can the synchronization process be done from the mysql shell? the UI is a little cumbersome to use, and more error prone if you want to repeat the process the same way once in a while

Comment: Check out Percona's pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync.

Comment: Matt - how about accepting your answer to close your ticket!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the migration wizard (available from menu `Database`) is a better choice for this scenario.